# How do I use MVC route special parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm aware of the special parameters `{controller}` and `{action}`, but I've seen blogs/posts throw in special parameters such as `{controller}/{action}/{*id}`. Besides the asterisk, what other special characters are available to use, and how would I use them?

On top of that, I'm confused on how to use route constraints. A common map that makes sense to me is

```
routes.MapRoute( "Blog",
                 "Blog/{d}/{m}/{y}",
                 new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" },
                 new { d = @"\d{1,2}", m = @"\d{1,2}", y = @"\d{4}" }
);
```

In the constraint object, the **d**, **m** and **y** all correspond to the parameters within the URL, which makes sense. On some blogs I've read though, I get thrown off when people start throwing in constraints on parameters which don't exist such as

```
contentType = new ContentTypeConstraint(ConstraintContentType.JSON)
```

or

```
IsRootAction = new IsRootActionConstraint()
```

Which object are `contentType` and `IsRootAction` defined? Are there any more properties besides these two?

UPDATE
I've done some more searching, and I've found out that under the hood a `new { controller = "Blog"}` is converted into a RouteValueDictionary. This is basically just shorthand. The parameters I was curious about (IsRootAction and ContentType) are just key names for the dictionary, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Action Constraints are either defined in the MVC framework, or defined by your code (preferably in Models) and implement the MVC interface IRouteConstraint.

See this answer for an example of how an Action Constraint is defined, this speaks specifically to your question about IsRootActionContraint.

[Having trouble with a simple MVC route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571970/having-trouble-with-a-simple-mvc-route/4600810#4600810)

I have not seen the {*...} notation, the general syntax is that each curly-parenthesized name is an extracted parameter from the matching URL.

Comment: I just found a reference to the {...?} syntax in this project: http://maproutes.codeplex.com/ the ? means Optional. Again though, I'm not familiar with this syntax and was unable to find a summary of these control characters myself, possibly a deprecated feature?