# ASP.NET ROUTES AND CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have already managed to get friendly urls working with my cms; however, what i want to know is: with asp.net 4.0 routes options, how do i get a root leaving routing?  When user types in www.mysite.com/page_name, which is aboutus, it goes to the page cms.aspx but leaves the other routes intact:

```
        routes.Clear();
        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "View Product",             // Route name
            "Products/{ProductName}",   // Route URL
            "~/products.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
        );


        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "ShoppingCart",       // Route name
            "{ShoppingCart}",   // Route URL
            "~/Basket.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
        );


        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "ShoppingCart",       // Route name
            "{ShoppingCart}",   // Route URL
            "~/Basket.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
        );

  // --->> How do i do this

  // Register a route for url/{pagename}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "cms",       // Route name
            "{}",   // Route URL
            "~/cms.aspx"        // Web page to handle route
        );
```

Comment: i am using this in asp.net webform app though not mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a root controller. This will allow you to eliminate the controller name and just have:
{url}/action 
It sounds like your intention is to clean up the URL's?

See: [Having trouble with a simple MVC route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571970/having-trouble-with-a-simple-mvc-route/4600810#4600810)